# How do I fix float division by zero error in this function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to make a grade calculator with a GUI. However when I press the button, my function does not print the results but instead throws me a "float division by zero" error. How could I fix this?

````
from tkinter import *

import tk as tk

main = Tk()

# --- FUNCTION ---
def program():
    try:
        print(float(GradeBox3.get()) - (float(GradeBox1.get()) * (1 - float(GradeBox2.get()))) / float(
            GradeBox2.get()))

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        result = 'error'

# --- MAIN ---
Label(main, text="Current Grade").grid(row=0)
tk.entry = Entry(main).grid(row=0, column=1)

Label(main, text='Weight of exam (Enter decimal then percentage ex: .30)').grid(row=2)
tk.entry = Entry(main).grid(row=2, column=1)

Label(main, text='Desired grade').grid(row=4)
tk.entry = Entry(main).grid(row=4, column=1)

mybutton = Button(main, text='Get your grade!', command=program).grid(row=6)

# --- VARS ---
GradeBox1 = tkinter.IntVar()
GradeBox2 = tkinter.IntVar()
GradeBox3 = tkinter.IntVar()


main.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Don't divide by zero. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: You haven't linked the three variables to the `Entry` boxes that (presumably) should set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three `IntVar` instances that default to 0, but no way of changing their values by way of the three `Entry` objects. So no matter what numbers you enter, your program retrieves `0` from each, and you end up trying to calculate `0.0 - (0.0 * (1 - 0.0)) / 0.0`.

Instead, you need to link each variable to the appropriate `Entry` using its `textvariable` keyword argument.

```
# --- VARS ---
GradeBox1 = tkinter.IntVar()
GradeBox2 = tkinter.IntVar()
GradeBox3 = tkinter.IntVar()

Label(main, text="Current Grade").grid(row=0)
Entry(main, textvariable=GradeBox1).grid(row=0, column=1)

Label(main, text='Weight of exam (Enter decimal then percentage ex: .30)').grid(row=2)
Entry(main, textvariable=GradeBox2).grid(row=2, column=1)

Label(main, text='Desired grade').grid(row=4)
Entry(main, textvariable=GradeBox3).grid(row=4, column=1)

mybutton = Button(main, text='Get your grade!', command=program).grid(row=6)



main.mainloop()
```